# QFile::copy says "can't open source file for input"?

Tags: qt, qfile

I'm going to copy one file using `QFile::copy` function but this function always returns false and `errorString` says :

```
"Cannot open D:/tmp/buf34.txt for input"
```

I tried to run this program with administrator privilege but nothing changed. My code is really simple :

```
  QString source = url.toLocalFile();
  QString destination = _dir.absolutePath()
            + QString("/%1").arg(QFileInfo(source).fileName());
  qDebug()<<"Cp from :" << source << " to : "<< destination;
  QFile file(source);
  qDebug()<<file.copy(destination);
  qDebug()<<file.errorString();
```

**Edit:**
I have QListView occupied with a `QFileSystemModel`. I try to drag one file from this ListView to a QLabel. For the QLabel a destination path is set. In drop event I try to copy file.

Comment: How about adding `qDebug() << "source exists: " << QFileInfo(source).exists();` to see if the source file exists?

Comment: No I'm sure that source file doesn't exist in destination. The error says that source file couldn't be opened.

Comment: How did the source file get there? Is it written by some other program which still could have the file open?

Comment: I set a QFileSystemModel model with a path for a listView. Then I drag one file from this listView to a label(Destination is set for this label ) . At the end of drop I try to copy the file selected from listView to label's directory !

Comment: @Roku ~> Is it related to ListView?! I can copy a file that is not in list view !

Comment: Unfortunately I have no idea.

Comment: @saeed I guess this file is opened by another `QFile::open`, if not: *"source"* exists? You may not copying one file that does not exist. If there is, you are trying to record in a directory with permissions (Windows Vista, Windows 7, etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`QFile::copy` uses `QFile::open` but overwrites the error message `open` would give by the unhelpful `"Cannot open %1 for input"` you got.

So, you should try opening the file yourself to get that original error message:

```
qDebug()<<file.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
qDebug()<<file.errorString();
```

Comment: Oh thank you ! Now the error is : **The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.** . `QUrl::toLocalFile` adds "\r\n" at the end of the string . so `source` is fileAddress + "\r\n" !

Comment: I just removed "\r\n" from the end and Now file copied successfully! But Do you know why this happened ?

Comment: @saeed I don't see anything in the source code of `QUrl::toLocalFile` that could add "\r\n" to the file name. It might have been added somewhere else.